# How to convert String to array of float in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var FloatArray:[[Float]] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...,[2,5,3]]
func savefile() {
        let arrayToSave = NSArray(array: FloatArray)
    arrayToSave.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
}

func loadfile() {
    if let loadArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as? [String]{
        //code
    }
}
```

**Step 1.**

```
var FloatArray: [[Float]] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...,[2,5,3]]
```

**Step 2.**

```
Save the FloatArray in the String file. String = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...,[2,5,3]]"
```

**Step 3.**     Then load the String file "`loadArray`" convert String to array of float.

How to convert String to array of float in Swift?

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question. Are you asking how to convert `loadArray` which is an array of Strings to `[[Float]]`?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to convert "loadArray" to array of [[Float]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `savefile()` and write the `FloatArray` (this is not a *type*, so you should use `camelCase` name convention here, `floatArray` ...) of type `[[Float]]`, the file written to will like something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <real>1</real>
        <real>2</real>
        <real>3</real>
    </array>
    <array>
        <real>4</real>
        <real>5</real>
        <real>6</real>
    </array>
    <array>
        <real>2</real>
        <real>5</real>
        <real>3</real>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```

This means that the type of the data written (array of floating point arrays) is also encoded in the file, and there is no reason to attempt to read this data and then convert it to `String` (this attempted conversion will fail).

Instead, simply modify your `loadFile()` method to read the contents of the file and attempt conversion to the type you already know was the type of the instance that was written to the file, namely a `[[Float]]` array (represented by an `NSArray` instance)

```
func loadfile() {
    if let loadArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as? [[Float]] {
        print(loadArray) // [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, 3.0]]
    }
}
```